# Agensgraph, graph databases, web development and webgis, advice on which way to go?

Tags: python, graph-databases, web-frameworks, agens-graph

More of an advice question here.

I'm well versed in Postgres/PostGIS, so I thought I'd look at Agensgraph aka Apache Graph Extension (AGE). This is a graph implementation in Postgresql which uses SQL for 'read-only' querying, but Cypher for pattern matching (adding/updating etc.).

Usefully this means I can use psycopg2 and python libaries to interact with the graph database. I've added nodes from dictionaries such as `{'id': '1', 'name': 'A', 'geometry': 'POLYGON ((10 10, 20 10, 20 20, 15 15, 15 5, 10 10))', 'type': 'Excavation area'}` here you can see a geometry column.

With all that working I'm looking to put a web interface on top, this should be able to interact with the data in the usual ways. I've used Django in the past, but it feels a little overkill for this. Further, having geospatial data, I'd need a webgis implementation, one which allows the creation/editing of spatial data.

So, with the above dict I can turn it into a geopandas GeoDataFrame, change it to geojson etc. I can structure generic queries to cope easily with the gathering of data `query = "MATCH(n: " + node_type + ") RETURN n"`. For the example it is a `Site` polygon node, so I can MATCH all the Sites and return a GeoDataFrame of all site polygons. While handling in Python is handy, I need to make a user interface for non-technical people.

With all this said, I have several questions:

- Am I storing the geometry in the best way to allow direct editing from a GIS web interface?
- Given my requirements what is the best framework/implementation to get this 'web ready'?
- The previous point, but including WebGIS?
- Any other pointers/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could give [NebulaGraph](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula) a try, it’s an OpenSource GraphDatabase.

It supports Geo-Spatial datatype/indexing, too. The Geo info could be persistent in Vertex/Edge properties.

Ref in docs:

- [Geo Functions](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.2.1/3.ngql-guide/6.functions-and-expressions/14.geo/)
- [Geo Datatype](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.2.1/3.ngql-guide/3.data-types/10.geography/)